# Input not file while creating App via Phonegap build API

Tags: api, phonegap-build

I am trying to create a phonegap app by using their createapp build API as described in

http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/developer_api_write.md.html

```
<?php
  $data = array(
    "file" => "@http://mywebsite.com/tmp/www.tar.gz",
    //"file" => "@actual path to/www.tar.gz",
    "data" => '{"title":"MyTestApp","create_method":"file"}'
  );

  $myusername = 'my build.phonegap user id';
  $password = 'my build.phonegap password';

  $handle = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $myusername.':'.$password);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps");
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-type: multipart/form-data;',
  ));
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

  $response = curl_exec($handle);
  print_r($response); 
?>
```

The www.tar.gz file is a valid file and it can be even download from the URL.

The code shows the below error

```
{"error":"Unable to create app: input is not a file"}
```

I raised this with phonegap support website and It looks my question doesn't get anyone's attention there. :-(

https://c.getsatisfaction.com/nitobi/topics/unable-to-create-app-input-is-not-a-file-df668pmjm93np

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @mradionov at https://github.com/mradionov/phonegap-build-api/issues/3

The problem is just because of the cURL changed in php and nothing to do with the phonegap api releases.

It looks the file upload method via curl got changed in php 5.6 version.

The below solved the issue

```
<?php

$data = array(
    "file" => new CurlFile("path to the file/abcd.tar.gz"),
    "data" => '{"title":"MyTestApp","create_method":"file"}'
);

$myusername = 'phonegap user id';
$password = 'phonegap password';

$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $myusername.':'.$password);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps");
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-type: multipart/form-data;',
));
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$response = curl_exec($handle);
print_r($response);
?>
```

In case if we use the OAuth then use the below

```
<?php
$data = array(
    "file" => new CurlFile("path to file/abcd.tar.gz"),
    "data" => '{"title":"MyTestApp","create_method":"file"}'
);

$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps?access_token=accesstoken");
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-type: multipart/form-data;',
));
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$response = curl_exec($handle);
print_r($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Malaiselvan,
Phonegap 2.x is obsolete. It is no longer supported. None of those examples work any longer.

As of 23 Sep 2015, the blog post is entitled [PhoneGap 5.2.0 Now Available on Build](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/09/23/phonegap_520_now_on_build/).

The means we are on Phonegap version 5.x.

If you want build your own remote IDE, then you want to use this documentation

http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/developer_api_api.md.html#PhoneGap%20Build%20Developer%20API

Best of Luck

Comment: Thanks for your time. I gone through those pages and I could see the authentication is done via Oath. That means I cannot submit the request with username and password?

Comment: Really tiered on solving my problem for the past 10 days.  I referred the documentation and I got the access_token.  How can I submit a create file request using the access_token?

Comment: No idea. There should be another StackOverflow tag named `phonegap-build-api` because that is what you are doing. I would suggest you continue on [nitobi](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi) with a new subject.